# Varchar(max) causing other other accesses of the record set to return null

Tags: sql-server, vbscript, asp-classic, adodb

With an SQL Server table set up as

```
A INT
B VARCHAR(MAX)
C INT
```

And accessessing this in ASP Classic

```
set RS = oConn.Execute("SELECT A,B,C FROM Table")

RS("A") returns A
RS("B") returns B
RS("C") returns ""
```

If we access C before B then we can get the value of C but if we ever use B then all subsequent RS calls return ""

One 'fix' we have found for this is changing the order of the fields in the table so

```
A INT
C INT
B VARCHAR(MAX)
```

But quite often we just use a SELECT B FROM Table

I'm guessing it is due to the older ADODB drivers not knowing what varchar(max) is or when it comes to an end. Is there any documentation of this anywhere?

Thanks

Comment: The duplicate has multiple answers but I think the easiest fix is using SQLNCLI instead of ADODB. (You should also consider moving on from ASP classic; it was [officially EOL at the end of 2021](https://www.sectorlink.com/article/say-goodbye-to-classic-asp-end-of-life-alert), but hasn't really been supported in any meaningful way since ASP.Net took hold.

Comment: Thank you! I wish we could but by time we got it all migrated Server 2022 will be EOL

Comment: You could use that argument the other way: if you don't start changing it, then they'll _both_ be EOL.

Comment: SQLNCLI is EoL as well, so in fact you probably should be looking at [MSOLEDBSQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/oledb-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16#3-microsoft-ole-db-driver-for-sql-server-msoledbsql-recommended).

Comment: @AaronBertrand, do you have an official Microsoft link that states ASP is EOL? The only think I could find is [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/general/asp-support-windows), which states it's tied to the OS/IIS lifecycle.

Comment: @Dan I'd love to see older versions of that doc (KB 2669020), because it has been alluded to in past answers here as being "alive" only until 10 years after Windows 8. Windows 8 was released in 2012. I also based this on [this Hanselman blog post, referencing ScottGu](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/lifecycle-support-for-classic-asp-in-windows). In any case, there's no doubt that it hasn't been getting any enhancements, bug fixes, or security updates in a loooong time. It isn't even enabled by default in IIS, and I doubt they'd talk to you if you called support about it.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, I just wish MS would state officially and clearly the support policy on mature technologies (or should I say zombie technologies) like ASP and ADO classic. Most devs know better than to use them for new development but legacy apps using them are an accident waiting to happen. Ironically, we are forced to upgrade newer technologies like .NET every couple of years yet the old stuff lingers for decades in limbo.